# javascript for ... in iterator mystery

Tags: javascript

Probably a slam dunk for someone, but I don't know why this code behaves the way it does:

```
testObjects = [ { "HI" : "how are you" } ];
for (obj in testObjects) { alert(obj.HI); }
```

It alerts 'undefined' (not "how are you"). Would somebody mind explaining?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`for` ... `in` iterates over *keys*, not *elements*. So `for(obj in testObjects)` means `obj` is the key, which in this case is 0 (because it is an array).

You could do

```
for (key in testObjects) {
  alert(testObjects[key].HI)
}
```

However, this is *not* a good practice. If you do it this way and somebody adds a method to `testOjbects` or to all arrays, it will iterate over that method as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the warning, it saved me from misery today

Comment: Heh, it's great to hear I was helpful to somebody :).

Answer (score 0):

Your `testObjects` variable is actually an array, not an object. Thus it obviously doesn’t have anything under the "HI" key (also, you are not supposed to use `for…in` loops for arrays in JavaScript; use regular `for` or `while` loops instead).

Either change your loop code to this: `for (obj in testObjects[0])`, or the variable definition to this `testObjects = { "HI" : "how are you" }`.

If your program does expect an array of objects, you’d need to set up two nested loops, probably like this:

```
for (var i=0, l=testObjects.length; i<l; i++) {
   for (var key in testObjects[i]) {
      // console.log(key + ' is ' + testObjects[i][key])
   }
}
```